# iOS - How to differentiate two or more CBPeripheral objects

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Now I'm looking for the solution to get the correct peripheral from IOS.

Our situation is we have 3-5 ble devices which have the same NAME (say "ZL_RELAY02") And we also have MAC of each devices. In android it very easy because we have MAC address but for IOS how can we identify to correct peripheral?

This case is iPhone device doesn't know all peripherals attributes before. it just have MAC & Password of target peripheral from server.

Hope someone have an idea to help us.

Thanks

Comment: @ Dome You can identify device using identifier as well.

Comment: Once you have discovered the right peripheral you can store its identifier for use in the future; see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353638/how-to-connect-to-peripheral-of-connected-bluetooth-device-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment89681003_51353638). For the initial discovery I would suggest that the name is suffixed with some value that is shown on the device (e.g. last 4 digits of MAC) or you connect to each peripheral and retrieve a characteristic value that holds the MAC or some serial number from the device

Comment: @Developer Thanks you for your reply, but how can we know that UUID is the correct peripherals we target? At the first time the iPhone has MAC & Password of that peripheral so how can it know which UUID is the correct one?

Comment: @ Dome - From didDiscover peripheral: delegate method you can fetch the identifier for a particular peripheral device. You can get uuid for each device from your server via service call.

Comment: @Developer If the same IOS device then it's OK but if there will be many IOS devices using it then we can't store UUID because it will generate uniquely , right?

Comment: Uuid of peripheral will be constant

Comment: Sorry if I ask silly question : That's mean I can use the UUID on another IOS device to connect those peripheral? As I understood UUID is constant on each IOS device but it will be different on other iOS device. When new user (IOS device) discover the ble then it will show their unique UUID, right? then how can new user know the target ble is which UUID if they know only MAC & Password.

Comment: @Developer the uuid is unique per iOS device. You cannot interchange discovered uuids between iOS devices.

Comment: @DomeAthikit as I said you will need to provide some information to the user that they can use to identify the device; a unique device name or some other value that you query from a characteristic on the device

Comment: @Developer  Thank you for your help , now I have solution to solve my problem. I have to put my identify data to a advertising data on peripherals. Thanks again for your kindly suggest.

Comment: @developer But the UUID of two BloodPressure devices is the same